# How to make my clearButton undo everything

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I draw some shapes and I want to clean my screen from them. So I made a button and called it clearButton and in my actionPreformed I clean them. It is not cleaning at all. So what I want is that my cleanButton to clean what I drew. Just look at the cleanButton and what I did to make it clean. It is long but I had to post the whole thing so it is more clear. Just ignore it and look only on what the cleanButton is doing. Thanks.

Main Class:

```
package kal;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import javax.swing.*;
import kal.Box;

public class Kal extends JFrame implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener,
  ActionListener
{
   int x=0, y=0; // last mouse location
   int pressx, pressy; // coords where the mouse is pressed

   JButton boxButton; // press this to put program in box-drawing mode
   JButton ovalButton;
   JButton triButton;
   JButton clearButton; 

   int mode = 0; // 0=ovals, 1=boxes, 2=triangles ..... 

   Oval theOval;
   Box theBox;
   Triangle theTriangle;
   Shape theShape;
   ColorPicker3 theColorPicker;

  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
     System.out.println("hi there.");
     new Kal();
  }

     // constructor, add MouseListener and MouseMotionListener
     public Kal()
     {
       setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

       setLayout( new FlowLayout() );

       boxButton = new JButton("box");
       add(boxButton);
       boxButton.addActionListener(this);

       ovalButton = new JButton("oval");
       add(ovalButton);
       ovalButton.addActionListener(this);

       triButton = new JButton("Triangle");
       add(triButton);
       triButton.addActionListener(this);

       clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
       add(clearButton);
       clearButton.addActionListener(this);

      addMouseListener(this);
      addMouseMotionListener(this);

      setSize( 500,500);
      setVisible( true);

      theColorPicker = new ColorPicker3();

    } 
     // returns a random color
     public Color randomColor()
     {
      int red = (int)(Math.random()*255);
      int green = (int)(Math.random()*255);
      int blue = (int)(Math.random()*255);
      return new Color(red,green,blue);
     }


      // note position of mouse xy globally, when clicked
      public void mouseClicked( MouseEvent e )
      {
        x = e.getX(); y = e.getY();
       System.out.println("click at x="+x+" y="+y);
      }
       public void mouseEntered( MouseEvent e ) {}

       // record where the mouse gets pressed
       public void mousePressed( MouseEvent e )
       {
         x = pressx = e.getX(); y = pressy = e.getY();

         Point p0 = new Point( x, y );
         Point p1 = new Point( pressx, pressy );

         if      ( mode==0 ) { theShape = theOval = new Oval( p0, p1, randomColor() );   }
         else if ( mode==1 ) { theShape = theBox = (new Box(p0 ,p1, randomColor()));}
         else if ( mode==2 ) { theShape = theTriangle = new Triangle( p0, p1,randomColor() ); }

         theShape.color = theColorPicker.b.color;
       }
          public void mouseExited( MouseEvent e ) {}
          public void mouseReleased( MouseEvent e ){}
          public void mouseMoved( MouseEvent e ) {}
          // note postion of mouse xy globally, when dragging
          public void mouseDragged( MouseEvent e )
       {
          x = e.getX(); y = e.getY();

          theShape.ends[0].x = x;
          theShape.ends[0].y = y;

         if ( mode==0 ) // Oval
         {
           theOval.ends[0].x = x; 
           theOval.ends[0].y = y; 
         }
         else if ( mode==1 ) // Box
         {
           theBox.ends[0].x = x;
           theBox.ends[0].y = y;
         }   

         else if ( mode==2) // Triangle 
         {
           theTriangle.ends[0].x = x;
           theTriangle.ends[0].y = y;
         }

           System.out.println("dragged to x="+x+" y="+y);
           repaint();
         }

          public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
         {
             if ( e.getSource()==ovalButton) { mode = 0; }
             else if ( e.getSource()==boxButton ) { mode = 1; }
             else if ( e.getSource()==triButton ) { mode = 2; }

        //clear all
    else if (e.getSource() == clearButton)
    {
        //theOval.clear();
            //theBox.clear();
            //theTriangle.clear();
    }
  repaint();   

     }

       public void paint(Graphics g )
       {
          super.paint(g); // is no super.paint(), then lines stay on screen 
          if ( theShape != null ) { theShape.drawMe(g); }

       }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What is being drawn in the painting method? theShape, and that's it. All those other variables, including theOval, theBox, and the Triangle, are just that reference variables completely independent of the one important variable, the theShape Variable. So put in the actionPerformed method where you want to clear your drawing:

```
theShape = null;
repaint();
```

That's it.

More importantly: never draw directly in a JFrame. Instead draw in the `paintComponent` method of a JPanel as the tutorials all tell you to do.